# Name of the following summation: $\sum_{a=b}^{\infty}{\binom{a-1}{b-1}x^{a-b}}=(1-x)^{-b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was proofing a formula when I meet a summation that I culdn't solve.
 After some efforts and investigations I've successfully recognized it in its generalized formula:
$$\sum_{a=b}^{\infty}{\binom{a-1}{b-1}x^{a-b}}=(1-x)^{-b}$$
that I saw online in a list of knowed series.

I've searched for a long time now, but I can't find information about it, even it's name, can you help me please?

I would like to prove it.

Comment: You can find it as a special case of Binomial series [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). Also, on a side note, changing index variable so that it starts from $0$ instead of $b$ is helpful to see it more clearly

Comment: @Adam In the special case paragraph of the link it says $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\binom{k+\beta}{k}z^k}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{\beta+1}}$$ but In my case I have to proof $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\binom{k+\beta}{\beta}z^k}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{\beta+1}}$$ Do you think that is still a Binomial series?

Comment: Surely, if $\beta$ is a non-negative integer (recall that then $\binom{k+\beta}{\beta}=\binom{k+\beta}{k+\beta-\beta} = \binom{k+\beta}{k} $)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a form of
the generalized binomial theorem.

It can be rewritten like this:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{a=b}^{\infty}{\binom{a-1}{b-1}x^{a-b}}
&=\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}{\binom{a+b-1}{b-1}x^{a}}\\
\end{array}
$

From the generalized binomial theorem:

$\begin{array}\\
(1-x)^{-b}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-b}{n} (-x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-b-k)}{n!} (-1)^nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(b+k)}{n!} (-1)^nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=b}^{n+b-1}(k)}{n!} x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n+b-1)!}{(b-1)!n!} x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+b-1}{n} x^n\\
\end{array}
$

and this is the same
with $n$ instead of $a$.